# MySQL Identical (almost) queries - one won't work when called by trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have two queries - both of which work in phpMyAdmin  but when called by a trigger one wont work (the bottom one)

```
INSERT INTO stats_objects(idCatalogue,strAttrName,strAttrVal)
SELECT CatId,'strName',l.strName FROM Catalogue c 
INNER JOIN item_live l ON c.idItem=l.id WHERE c.id=CatId;       OK

INSERT INTO stats_objects(idCatalogue,strAttrName,strAttrVal)
SELECT CatId,'strOS',h.strOS FROM Catalogue c 
INNER JOIN hosting_live h ON h.idItem=c.idItem WHERE c.id=CatId;    BROKEN
```

The table structure has the data in hosting_live with a one to one with item_live on h.idItem=l.id and item live has a one to one with each unique entry in catalogue on c.idItem=l.id.

Am I staring at the bleeding obvious again or are there subtleties to MySQL triggers and procedures I am missing. Both of these are in the same procedure called by the same trigger one following the other. No temporary tables - no commits that I can see, no dynamic SQL. The trigger is on Catalogue but I can't see I am changing Catalogue.

Anyone got better eyes and a fresher mind than me?

EDIT:  Trigger code as requested

```
CREATE TRIGGER aiCatalogue AFTER INSERT ON catalogue FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN 
  /* do other stuff with unrelated tables */

   CALL StatsObjectInsert(NEW.id);

END$$
```

Pretty basic when stripped of all the meat which calls

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StatsObjectInsert(IN CatId int(10))
BEGIN

/* the procedure containing the above */

END$$
```

Comment: Showing the relevant trigger code will help.

Comment: Also in your broken statement there is no table aliased with "l", yet you join on `l.id`

Comment: I almost thought you had found it - alas it was my own edit of an edit that was broken - fixed in the above

Answer (score 0):

The second query joins on `h.idItem=l.id`

There is no table aliased as `L`. It should probably be `c`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. The answer to this was the order of inserts of upstream objects.

I am inserting an object that is broken down into common data and attributes across two tables. Conceptually I am inserting one item but am in fact performing two inserts.  The trigger was associated with the common data which was firing of a sequence to update the catalogue.

The catalogue was triggering an update to a stats engine to tell it that there was a new item and to update its internal model.  This in turn was attempting to call the object specific attributes.

The problem was that because the trigger was firing on the first part of a two part insert the attribute data did not exist yet and so the stats engine could not use it and it  failed - but when I hard coded an id to test it worked fine because it was against an object that I knew existed that had already been created.

So Lesson?  Triggers on the first part of a two part insert will fire before the second part has started - so don't expect a downstream trigger to be able to find the data if it doesn't exist.

Other lesson: Think before deciding to renormalize your tables...